# Expressão regular em string XML

Tags: php, xml, regex

Olá, estou usando uma biblioteca em PHP para gerar uns words com alguns parametros.

A biblioteca é a PHPWord, quando eu carrego um arquivo (DOCX) ela abre o arquivo document.xml dentro do arquivo compactado DOCX.

> Exemplo:

```
<?php
$phpWord = new PHPWord('teste.docx');
$phpWord->setValue('oi', 'tudo bem');
```

O problema é que o XML do word deveria ficar assim:

```
<w:t>${oi}</w:t>
```

Mas está ficando assim (em alguns casos):

```
${</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="OLE_LINK1"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00036D2C"><w:t>oi</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/><w:r w:rsidRPr="00036D2C"><w:t>}</w:t>
```

Porque o setValue do PHPWord faz um replace na string carregada

```
/**
 * Set a Template value
 * 
 * @param mixed $search
 * @param mixed $replace
 */
public function setValue($search, $replace) {
    if(substr($search, 0, 2) !== '${' && substr($search, -1) !== '}') {
        $search = '${'.$search.'}';
    }

    if(!is_array($replace)) {
        $replace = utf8_encode($replace);
    }



    $this->_documentXML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_documentXML);
}
```

Como eu poderia corrigir isso usando expressão regular? Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como compartilhar um exemplo funcional chamando esta função?

E o que você quer dizer por "em alguns casos"?

Comment: Olá Pedro na pergunta já tem o exemplo. Vlws

Comment: Desculpe, não fui claro o suficiente. Qual instância de entrada você está usando nesse teste.docx?

Comment: E por que isso não estaria correto?
Repare que `<w:t>oi</w:t>` está contido no segundo exemplo. Qual a diferença no resultado final com o markup extra?

Answer (score 0):

Essa regex captura os caracteres não especiais que estão entre as tags `<w:t>`
 e `<\/w:t>`

```
(<w:t>[a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/w:t>)
```

Ela retornaria `<w:t>oi</w:t>` aí você poderia usar um replace para colocar `${` e `}`.

Comment: Não funcionava... ele não fazia o replace

Comment: o replace deve ser feito através de um método, por fora da regex, use o retorno da regex e adicione esses caracteres amigo